# Gradle - Android Studio Update 0.6.0 Plugin issue

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Need your help.I updated Android Studio to latest one and i am getting this message in issue log.

Error:The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.8.3).

Starting with version 0.9.0 incompatible changes were introduced in the build language.
Please read the migration guide to learn how to update your project.
Open migration guide, fix plug-in version and re-import project

Please Let me know What should i do.

Regards

Comment: Do what it says. Read the migration guide. If you then have questions, let us know what you tried.

Comment: thanks @mweathers i fixed that issue with the  help of Android Studio 0.6.0 gradle Plugin compatibility.Which says use 0.11.+